# authStateChanges() updates only after hot restart when a new user is registered in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, riverpod

The stream from `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` method updates automatically when an existing user logs in or logs out and the change is reflected in the UI but when a new user is registered then the stream is updated only after hot restart.

I am using **flutter 2.8.1** and **riverpod** (for state management).

Here is the code for AuthService.dart. (The class which handles authentication)

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthServices{

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //The stream for auth changes
  Stream<User?> get authState => _auth.authStateChanges();

  //Sign In with email and password
  Future<void> signInWithEmailPassword(String email,String password)async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = userCredential.user;
      print(user!.uid);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if(e.code=='user-not-found')
        print('No user exists with these credentials');
      else if(e.code== 'wrong-password')
        print('The password entered is wrong');
    }
  }

  //Create user with email and password
  Future<void> registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email,String password) async{
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = userCredential.user;
      print(user!.email);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  //Sign Out
  Future signOut()async{
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

The stream provider class

```
import 'package:edu_opt/services/auth_services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final authStreamProvider = StreamProvider((ref) {
  return AuthServices().authState;

});
```

The **Wrapper.dart** class which updates the UI of the app based on the authentication state received from the authStreamProvider.

```
import 'package:edu_opt/providers/auth_state_provider.dart';
import 'package:edu_opt/screens/authenticate/login/login.dart';
import 'package:edu_opt/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class Wrapper extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Wrapper({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    var authStream = ref.watch(authStreamProvider);

    return authStream.when(
        data: (data){
          if(data!=null) {
            print('logged in');
            return const Home();
          } else {
            print('logged out');
            return const Login();
          }
        },
        error: (error,stackTrace) => throw error,
        loading: ()=> const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
    );
  }
}
```

The text button in the class for registration of new user which triggers the `registerWithEmailAndPassword()` function.

```
TextButton(
     onPressed: ()async{
       if (_formKey.currentState!.validate() && _password==_confirmPassword) {
           await AuthServices().registerWithEmailAndPassword(_email!, _password!);
           print('account created');
        }
      },
    child: Text('Register',style: _theme.textTheme.button,))
```

Comment: Facing the same issue, any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

So after debugging for 2 hours, I found out that FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword function automatically logs you in. Since you're already logged in and then try to log in again, FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges() will not be triggered at that time.

So calling FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(); just after createUserWithEmailAndPassword solves the issue (at least for me).

Comment: Thanks Anirudh. I got your logic. The trouble arose because I was using `Navigator.pushReplaced` for navigation between the Login and the Register Page. In order to sort this out I had to wrap both the pages with an authentiate class and make use of a toggle function to switch between the views. Then finally replacing the `Login()` with `Authenticate()` in the wrapper class solved my problem and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I too got stuck with this for an hour and **here's what i found...**

**In signUp page,**
after creating new user with `FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword();`

**signout in the same page**(signUp page) before moving/navigating to Login page using

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
FirebaseFirestore.instance.terminate();
FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
```

- This problem is created because when you create new user with
  **FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()**
- It will automatically login this new user and when you try to login the
  app, it becomes irresponsive and becomes responsive after **"hot restart"**.